# POST on JAVA Restful WebService URL from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, rest

I have implemented a RESTful web Service in java which inserts data into MySQL db, I have tested this using POSTER in mozila firefox and also in google chrome. My Web Service takes a String with the POST request, now I am unable to utilize WEB SERVICE using JS: the code making POST request on WEB SERVICE URL is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/AgentWS/webresources/Items',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: 'content='+content,
            success: function (data) {
            alert(content);

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
}
        });
```

The alert in success function is also not displayed plus the dialog error is showing a dialog with : Error: on it'

Server Side code is:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String postXml(String content) {
    //TODO
    // return Response.created(context.getAbsolutePath()).build();
    StringTokenizer sp = new StringTokenizer(content, "&");

    String agentName = sp.nextToken();
    String agentId = sp.nextToken();
    String agentState = sp.nextToken();
    String agentExtension = sp.nextToken();
    String agentDeviceState = sp.nextToken();
    String agentDeviceStateChangeTime = sp.nextToken();
    DBConection conn = new DBConection();
    conn.insertAgentActivityInfo(agentName, agentId, agentState, agentExtension, agentDeviceState, agentDeviceStateChangeTime);

    return agentName + " " + agentId + " " + agentState + " " + agentExtension + " " + agentDeviceState + " " + agentDeviceStateChangeTime;
}
```

Comment: what is the error that your are facing? Its a good practice to ask question by mentioning the error that you face while running.

Comment: Debug it with firebug (or similar).  Check the request that was sent, the HTTP response code, and the response.  If the error is really server side, check the error logs in your java app.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `data: 'content='+content,` is posting invalid XML to the server and you are getting *500 Internal Server Error*. Can you try setting the `data` to just the XML content? like

```
...
data: content,
....
```

## EDIT

If all you want is a simple post

### Java

```
@POST
public String postXml(String content) {
  //TODO
  // return Response.created(context.getAbsolutePath()).build();
  StringTokenizer sp = new StringTokenizer(content, "&");

  String agentName = sp.nextToken();
  ...

  return agentName + " " + agentId + " " + agentState + " " + agentExtension + " " + agentDeviceState + " " + agentDeviceStateChangeTime;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/AgentWS/webresources/Items',
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'content=1&2&3&4&5&5',
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);

  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
  }
});
```

Comment: the content variable contains xml string in it'

Comment: All the more reason not to mangle the XML post because the server sees `content=<?xml version="1.0"....` which cannot be parsed to valid XML

Comment: I have just edited the server Side code of my POST to the question'

Comment: you are not consuming xml content at all... you simply want to pass a `&` delimited string to the server. Where are you using xml?

Comment: yes' thats what I am doing' but I am still unable to do that', although I have done that using poster and rest console

Comment: All I need is to POST a '&' delimited String to my function' kindly guide a little'

Comment: what is the value of `content` that you are trying to `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the data you are sending,

`data: 'content='+content` should be replaced with a name for the parameter like

`data: {content:'content='+content}`

and check what you are doing on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i think, you should write a model class Agent in server side like this :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class Agent
{
private String agentName;
private String agentId; 
private String agentState; 
private String agentExtension; 
private String agentDeviceState; 
private String agentDeviceStateChangeTime;

public String getAgentName() {
    return agentName;
}
public void setAgentName(String agentName) {
    this.agentName = agentName;
}
public String getAgentId() {
    return agentId;
}
public void setAgentId(String agentId) {
    this.agentId = agentId;
}
public String getAgentState() {
    return agentState;
}
public void setAgentState(String agentState) {
    this.agentState = agentState;
}
public String getAgentExtension() {
    return agentExtension;
}
public void setAgentExtension(String agentExtension) {
    this.agentExtension = agentExtension;
}
public String getAgentDeviceState() {
    return agentDeviceState;
}
public void setAgentDeviceState(String agentDeviceState) {
    this.agentDeviceState = agentDeviceState;
}
public String getAgentDeviceStateChangeTime() {
    return agentDeviceStateChangeTime;
}
public void setAgentDeviceStateChangeTime(String agentDeviceStateChangeTime) {
    this.agentDeviceStateChangeTime = agentDeviceStateChangeTime;
}
}
```

And the server rest service that you have should be changed little bit :

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String postXml(Agent agent) {}
```

Inside this method you can use "agent" object, that is passed, to retrieve all the values sent by the client like `agent.getAgentName()`

Now the payload(or request body) that should contain something like this:

```
<Agent>
<agentName></agentName>
<agentId></agentId>
<agentState></agentState>
<agentExtension></agentExtension>
<agentDeviceState></agentDeviceState>
<agentDeviceStateChangeTime></agentDeviceStateChangeTime>
</Agent>
```

I hope it is of some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess without the error code and message but:

change

```
data: 'content='+content
```

to

```
data: { content : content } // format as json
```

And in your java resource:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String postXml(String content)
// read content as json
```